# How can I add hotkeys with Safari extension

Tags: safari

Can I listen to hotkeys with safari extension?

I want to respond to `Cmd+SomeKey` with action done by extension, but I've read intro on apple developer and there is nothing about hotkeys.

> You can add custom buttons to the Safari toolbar, create bars of your own, add contextual menu items, display content in bars or tabs, and inject scripts and style sheets into webpages.

No single word about hotkeys, and google doesn't find any article about that. So is it possible at all? If it is possible, where can I get additional info?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done -- someone helped me to set it up for my browser window resizer extension. You need to have an injected script that checks for a specific keypress/combo then send a message back to your toolbar or global page. Here's an example on github of an [inject script to monitor for specific keypresses (alt-1 to alt-0)](https://github.com/sixfoot1/Resizer/blob/master/Resizer.safariextension/Inject.js) and here's an example of doing something with the message [lines 92-108 & 131 of this toolbar page](https://github.com/sixfoot1/Resizer/blob/master/Resizer.safariextension/Toolbar.html).